# Yii2: Как сохранять мульти поле в базу данных?

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

Подскажите как в Yii 2 правильно создать поле с множественным значением типа чекбокс и записать его в БД?

Вот пример моего поля в _form

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'type')->checkboxList(['t01' => 'Покупка', 't02' => 'Продажа', 't03' => 'Аренда']); ?>
```

По идее хочу сохранять ключи в одну ячейку через запятую. Я так понимаю где-то нужно перед сохранением преобразовать данные из этого поля в строку и в update наоборот?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в понимании как правильно реализовать подобный трюк.

Comment: Я бы сделал три поля, чтобы не извращаться с explode/imlode

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня подтолкнули именно в ту сторону, что я искал, как закончу - опубликую решение.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать таблицу типов, потом смежную таблицу где будут хранится id_product, id_type

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ готовый пример кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148215)